# Qooxdoo default tab index not working properly

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

According to the Qooxdoo Beginner's Guide 
[here](http://tinyurl.com/oafl4a8) the default tab index for the widgets is set in the order in which the widgets are added to a container. But in this [code](http://tinyurl.com/qclpuqg) in the playground this for some reason is not happening. Is this a qooxdoo bug or is something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book is somewhat outdated. I'm not sure if it worked like stated in the book at some time or if it hasn't worked like that all along. Anyway, the [manual](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.5/pages/desktop/ui_interaction.html#focus-handling) (which is the preferred and most up-to-date source of information) states:

> The tab handling in qooxdoo is based on coordinates of each widget on
>   the screen. It follows the visible structure and not the internal
>   application (or even markup) structure.

So it's not a bug - you have to set the tab index manually if you want more control over this behavior.

Comment: What you are saying seems logic enough. But why the tab index doesn't continue per group box? In the example in the playground tab index jumps from group 1 textbox1 to group 2 texbox2 and then group1 texbox2 and so on... it seems more logic to go like group1 textbox1, textbox2 ... and then group2 textbox1, textbox2 etc...

Comment: Yes, you're right ("seems more logic ..."). Probably this use case wasn't thought of back then. You can open an enhancement bug, but I guess, that this won't be fixed soon. But PRs are always welcome. :)